# Disabling Visual Studio 2022 SSL developer certificate generation for docker linux container

Tags: docker, debugging, visual-studio-2022

I've managed to solve a solution for https communication inbetween services in development, it is based on scripted openssl certification generation and a command in the Dockerfile to trust it on linux.

My problem is that when debugging in visual studio it tells tell me that my certificate is invalid, although just using docker run or compose file with the same arguments works completely fine.

I see that visual studio has its own mechanic to mount a token service etc, that might be interfering with my solution, can I disable it? Perhaps by unmounting a mounted file during build? Some visual studio configuration would be optimal however.

Thankful for all ideas, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In the build command that Visual Studio performs, it specifies '--target base', and my script was not running in 'base' section in my Dockerfile. I moved it there and it works! I also have found some documentation about this.

Edit: heres the link to the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2022. Actually explains alot.

Comment: You should add the link to the documentation you found